# Add Character Selection function to Multiplayer game

Tags: javascript, c#, multiplayer

I've created a multi-player game using a Multiplayer Photon Network tutorial. It works fine when at runtime, spawning the same character for multiple users. But who wants to play a game with all the same characters running around. I'm trying to incorporate a 2nd tutorial that shows how to set up character selection. The Multiplayer Network Photon tutorial is in C#, the Character Selection tut is in Javascript. The tuts work independently but are not talking to each other. Here is the CharacterSelection code:

```
#pragma strict
//this is the currently selected Player. Also the one that will be saved to PlayerPrefs
var selectedPlayer : int = 0;

function Update() 
{ 
if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp (0)) {
    var ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay (Input.mousePosition);
    var hit : RaycastHit;

    if (Physics.Raycast (ray, hit, 100))
    {
            // The pink text is where you would put the name of 
the object you want to click on (has attached collider).

                if(hit.collider.name == "Player1") 
            SelectedCharacter1(); //Sends this click down to a 
function called "SelectedCharacter1(). Which is where all of our stuff happens.

            if(hit.collider.name == "Player2")
            SelectedCharacter2();

            if(hit.collider.name == "Player3")
            SelectedCharacter3();
        } 
        else
        {
        return;               
        }
    } 
}

function SelectedCharacter1() {
    Debug.Log ("Character 1 SELECTED"); //Print out in the Unity console 
which character was selected.
    selectedPlayer = 1;
    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("selectedPlayer", (selectedPlayer));
}

function SelectedCharacter2() {
    Debug.Log ("Character 2 SELECTED");
    selectedPlayer = 2;
    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("selectedPlayer", (selectedPlayer));
}

function SelectedCharacter3() {
    Debug.Log ("Character 3 SELECTED");
    selectedPlayer = 3;
    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("selectedPlayer", (selectedPlayer));
}
```

Here is the CharacterSpawn Javascript.

```
#pragma strict
//these are the player prefabs that will be automagically plugged in for us.
var player01Prefab : GameObject;
var player02Prefab : GameObject;
var player03Prefab : GameObject;

//this is where the script placed in the level inputs in this number for the player          
who was selected
//and saved by playerPrefs
var savedPlayer : int = 0;

//this is called first before the Start function, so make sure it loads everthing 
needed first.
function Awake() {

    // Let's grab the saved data for each player and grab that integer to use 
to load that player in the world
    savedPlayer = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("selectedPlayer");

player01Prefab = GameObject.Find("Player1");
player02Prefab = GameObject.Find("Player2");
player03Prefab = GameObject.Find("Player3");

    if(savedPlayer == 0) //if we've not selected any player initially lets just 
use Player 1 
        {                   
        player01Prefab.SetActiveRecursively(true);
        player02Prefab.SetActiveRecursively(false);
    player03Prefab.SetActiveRecursively(false);
        }
    else if(savedPlayer == 1) //if we've set the player to 1 from playerprefs then 
        {                   
        player01Prefab.SetActiveRecursively(true);
        player02Prefab.SetActiveRecursively(false);
        player03Prefab.SetActiveRecursively(false);
        }
    else if(savedPlayer == 2) //if we've set the player to 2 from playerprefs then 
        {                   
        player02Prefab.SetActiveRecursively(true);
        player01Prefab.SetActiveRecursively(false);
        player03Prefab.SetActiveRecursively(false);
        }
    else if(savedPlayer == 3) //if we've set the player to 3 from playerprefs then 
        {                   
        player03Prefab.SetActiveRecursively(true);
        player01Prefab.SetActiveRecursively(false);
        player02Prefab.SetActiveRecursively(false);

        }
}
```

Here is the C# Network Manager code.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class NetworkManager : Photon.MonoBehaviour {
    public Camera standbyCamera; 



    void Start () {
        Connect ();
    }

    void Connect() {
        PhotonNetwork.ConnectUsingSettings( "MultiFPS" );
    }

    void OnGUI () {
        GUILayout.Label ( PhotonNetwork.connectionStateDetailed.ToString () );
    }

    void OnJoinedLobby() {
        PhotonNetwork.JoinRandomRoom();

    }

    void OnPhotonRandomJoinFailed() {
        PhotonNetwork.CreateRoom( null );

    }
    void OnJoinedRoom() {
        Debug.Log ("OnJoinedRoom");

        SpawnSelectedPlayer();
    }
```

The Character Spawn script is on a scene where you can click on a game object and that character should spawn into another scene, the first level.

Here is the Loadlevel Javascript:

```
// JavaScript
function OnGUI () {
    // Make a background box
    GUI.Box (Rect (10,10,100,90), "Load Level");

    // Make the first button. If it is pressed, Application.Loadlevel (1) will
 be executed
    if (GUI.Button (Rect (20,40,80,20), "Level 1"))
{
    Application.LoadLevel ("Whyyyyyyy");
}
}
```

I converted the Javascript CharacterSpawn into C# and mashed it up with the NetworkManager code as they seemed to handle the spawning. The following nonworking code is my attempt at
trying to connect my Character Selection to my Network Manager/Spawn setup.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class NetworkManager : Photon.MonoBehaviour {
    //these are the player prefabs that will be automagically plugged in for us.
    GameObject character1;
    GameObject character2;
    GameObject character3;
    GameObject character4;

    public Camera standbyCamera; 

//this is where the script placed in the level inputs in this number for the 
player who was selected
    //and saved by playerPrefs
    int savedPlayer = 0;

    //this is called first before the Start function, so make sure it 
loads everthing needed first.

        void  Awake (){

    // Let's grab the saved data for each player and grab that integer to 
use to load that player in the world
        savedPlayer = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("selectedPlayer");

        character1Prefab = GameObject.Find("Player1");
        character2Prefab = GameObject.Find("Player2");
        character3Prefab = GameObject.Find("Player3");

        if(savedPlayer == 0) //if we've not selected any player initially 
lets just use Player 1 
        {                   
            player01Prefab.SetActiveRecursively(true);
            player02Prefab.SetActiveRecursively(false);
            player03Prefab.SetActiveRecursively(false);
        }
        else if(savedPlayer == 1) //if we've set the player to 1 
    from   playerprefs then 

        {                   
            player01Prefab.SetActiveRecursively(true);
            player02Prefab.SetActiveRecursively(false);
            player03Prefab.SetActiveRecursively(false);
        }
        else if(savedPlayer == 2) //if we've set the player to 2 
    from playerprefs then 
        {                   
            player02Prefab.SetActiveRecursively(true);
            player01Prefab.SetActiveRecursively(false);
            player03Prefab.SetActiveRecursively(false);
        }
    else if(savedPlayer == 3) //if we've set the player to 3 from 
playerprefs then 
        {                   
            player03Prefab.SetActiveRecursively(true);
            player01Prefab.SetActiveRecursively(false);
            player02Prefab.SetActiveRecursively(false);

        }

        void Start () {
            Connect ();
        }

        void Connect() {
            PhotonNetwork.ConnectUsingSettings( "MultiFPS" );
        }

        void OnGUI () {
    GUILayout.Label ( PhotonNetwork.connectionStateDetailed.ToString   () );
        }

        void OnJoinedLobby() {
            PhotonNetwork.JoinRandomRoom();

        }

        void OnPhotonRandomJoinFailed() {
            PhotonNetwork.CreateRoom( null );

        }
        void OnJoinedRoom() {
            Debug.Log ("OnJoinedRoom");

            SpawnSelectedPlayer();
        }

        void SelectedPlayer() {
            PhotonNetwork.Instantiate("SelectedPlayer", Vector3.zero,   
 Quaternion.identity, 0);
            standbyCamera.enabled = false;

        }




    }
```

The error I get states that I can't add the 'void start' line as I did. A GUI Level1 start button on the Character selection scene sucessfully takes the user to the Level One where connection to the network is established, and a character is spawned, but not the 'selected player from the selection scene. As separate scripts the SelectedPlayer is not recognized. Your assistance would be greatly appreciated. I'm at wit's end, but feel so close, yet so far. Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: As far as I can tell from this code the function Start() is within the function Awake(). This is not legal in C#. Maybe you are just missing a closing curly brace?

Comment: Thanks svinja I will play around some more and add a closing curly brace.